A geometry puzzle
I'm having a hard time solving this geometry puzzle.
Consider two intersecting lines, and a circle intersecting these two lines. We add to this configuration two externally tangent circles (1 and 4) and two internally tangent circles (2 and 3). They are all tangent to the lines.

We must show that : $$r_1r_4 = r_2r_3$$

What I tried for the moment :
I'm kinda lost. I tried to draw the bisector to deduce interesting relationships, but in vain.
I would like to use the fact that two circles with respective radii $R$ and $r$ are tangent externally (resp. internally) if and only if the distance between their centers is $R+r$ (resp. $R-r$).
Any help would be nice :^)

The centers of all 5 circles need not be collinear. Here's a better example of the setup:


Clarification: is the center of the large circle on the angle bisector between the lines?

@OscarLanzi Not necessarily but WE can suppose it first to make it simpler maybe

This is a sangaku called Ohara's theorem (not O' Hara...). See here

About Ohara's methods, see the deep study here

Note: My comment was assuming that all the centers of the circles were on the same line, based on a quick glance of OP's diagram. Jean's link indicates that assumption isn't valid.

A vaguely related problem which may provide some insight: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry

I'm pretty sure the center of the circles must all lie on the angle bisector.  If the center of a circle and the angle bisector don't intersect than the diagram is asymmetric which would violate the orientation being arbitrary.  (Of course one would like a stronger proof than that.)... (Isn't there a plane geom. theorem that the perpendiculars to tangents of a circle intersect at the center?)

Seems to me that the large circle is a red herring.  By similar triangles, the ratio of radii of two touching circles is constant, and the result follows.

@dm63: "Seems to me that the large circle is a red herring." See the "better example" figure. The smaller circles need not be touching each other.

Ah understood thx
